# Centering & zooming on area of interest

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api

For example, our subject of interest are coffeeshops, and user wants to lookup all coffeeshops located in Mitte district of Berlin.
In order to do that he selects `Berlin` as city, `Mitte` as district and submits form.

Than he should see map that is zoomed  and centered on the given district, like https://nimbus.everhelper.me/client/notes/share/323673/Iiw6bfSPRoJTTTLSUte0RPhmRv28y4CQ/

As the last step  application needs to get the borders of the displayed area and query server for all available coffeeshops inside it.

I'm not familiar with the Google Maps API very much and have only a general plan how to do that:

- find POI polygon
- initialize map centered and zoomed on the POI polygon
- get the displayed area bounds
- do the other work

the first two steps seems to be black box for me now. Can anyone familiar with google maps API please help break this down into the consecutive steps that I can just implement with JavaScript?

Comment: What's the extent of your project?  Berlin only? Where do you get the data from (json, google places, ..)?